# Grep value from json file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, json

my json file looks something like this

```
[{"product":"Apple","id":"2134"},{"product":"Mango","id":"4567"}]
```

I want to grep/sed/awk 'id' for given 'product'.

Output:

```
Enter product : Apple
Your product id is : 2134
```

Comment: You'd be better off using ruby or python and importing a json library than using bash for this. Ruby/python will parse the json file for you and make the data accessible.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is clumsy, but here is what I could get -

```
sed  's/.*\(Apple\)[^:]*:"\([0-9]*\)".*/Enter product ID: \1\nYour  product ID is: \2/' 3
Enter product ID: Apple
Your product ID is: 2134

sed  's/.*\(Mango\)[^:]*:"\([0-9]*\)".*/Enter product ID: \1\nYour product ID is: \2/' 3
Enter product ID: Mango
Your product ID is: 4567
```

Edited based on latest input which is slightly different

```
./prod.sed Apple
Enter product ID: Apple
Your product ID is: 1234

./prod.sed Mango
Enter product ID: Mango
Your product ID is: 12345

prod.sed (use 3rd line for publishName)

#sed  's/.*product_id":"\(Apple\).*"productBuildId":"\([0-9]*\)".*/Enter product ID: \1\nYour product ID is: \2/' data
sed  's/.*product_id":"\('"$1"'\).*"productBuildId":"\([0-9]*\)".*/Enter product ID: \1\nYour product ID is: \2/' data
sed  's/.*product_id":"\('"$1"'\)","publishName":"\([^"]*\)".*/Enter product ID: \1\nYour publish ID is: \2/' data

explanation : substitute the string <anything> Mango <anything other than :> : <number> with -> Your product ID is: Mango <next line> 
Your product ID is : <the number we got> 

 \1 and \2 save the matched expression in \(..\) for later use.
```

Comment: I checked with my text file, the sed command here is not working, its displaying whole of file. Can you explain me on this command?

Comment: Added explanation. Do you have separate lines in the file or all in 1 line ?

Comment: I have all in 1 line.

Comment: how do I execute this? should I just enter the whole thing in the prompt? if so its not working.

Comment: yes. Could you put the input file somewhere (pastebin maybe?) and put the link here.

Comment: [{"product_id":"Apple","publishName":"Fruit_01","productBuildId":"1234","revision":1,"platform":"Linux"}],[{"product_id":"Mango","publishName":"Fruit_02","productBuildId":"12345","revision":1,"platform":"Linux"}]

Comment: I want to fetch "publishName" for say product_id "Apple".

Comment: thanks. This worked. But this is also fetching other texts which is not intended. I am not putting the this in a seperate sed file, rather im putting 3rd line in a .sh file

Answer (score 6):

Use a JSON aware tool. Perl has the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) library:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $json = '[{"product":"Apple","id":"2134"},{"product":"Mango","id":"4567"}]';

print 'Enter product: ';
chomp( my $product = <> );

print 'Your product id is: ', 
    (grep $_->{product} eq 'Apple', @{ from_json($json) })[0]{id}, "\n";
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. But I am putting this in a .sh file.

Comment: `perl -MJSON -e 'print map { $_ -> {id} } grep { $_ -> {product} eq "Apple" } @{decode_json( do { local $/; <> } )};' ` - if you really must use shell. But honestly? `perl` can do everything a shell script can, and SO MUCH more.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `json` parser, not `sed`/`grep`/`awk`.

Using Python `json` module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    f_json = json.load(f)
    print 'Enter product : ' + f_json[0]['product'] + '\nYour product id is : ' + f_json[0]['id']
```

**Output:**

```
Enter product : Apple
Your product id is : 2134
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. I need to put this in a .sh file. and I dont use any modules

Answer (score 2):

I created a file called json that looks like this:

```
[{"product":"Apple","id":"2134"},{"product":"Mango","id":"4567"},{"product":"Pear","id":"1111"},{"product":"Banana","id":"2222"}]
```

Then I run this on the command line:

```
 cat json | sed -e 's/.\?{"product"\:\"\([^\"]\+\)\","id"\:\"\([[:digit:]]\+\)[^}]}\+.\?/Enter Product : \1\nYour Product id is : \2\n/mgi'
```

The output is this:

```
Enter Product : Apple
Your Product id is : 2134
Enter Product : Mango
Your Product id is : 4567
Enter Product : Pear
Your Product id is : 1111
Enter Product : Banana
Your Product id is : 2222
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. As I see 'id' is made for number only. Can you show me how we can change this for something like below

Comment: [{"product_id":"Apple","publishName":"Fruit_01","productBuildId":"1234","revisio‌​n":1,"platform":"Linux"}],[{"product_id":"Mango","publishName":"Fruit_02","produc‌​tBuildId":"12345","revision":1,"platform":"Linux"}]
I want to fetch "publishName" for say product_id "Apple"

Comment: change [[:digit:]] to [[:alpha:][:digit:]]

Comment: Also for you json string, it is pretty much the same thing, you just have to add for the extra attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Given a product name in `$name`, the ID of that product could be parsed out using `jq` like so:

```
jq -r --arg name "$name" '.[] | select(.product == $name).id' file.json
```

Example:

```
$ cat file.json
[{"product":"Apple","id":"2134"},{"product":"Mango","id":"4567"}]
```

```
$ name=Apple
$ jq -r --arg name "$name" '.[] | select(.product == $name).id' file.json
2134
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, the following `sed` command ...

```sh
sed -e 's/[}"]*\(.\)[{"]*/\1/g;y/,/\n/' <your_input
```

...will write to output...

```
[product:Apple
id:2134
product:Mango
id:4567]
```

...probably you can take it from there.